"numpy.ndarray" is not callable
I am getting a type error if I run this code twice or multiple times. That means if I run it once, it won't show any error but if I run it multiple times it will show an error.
Some parts of the code:
param_g= {'alpha':[0.001,0.01,0.1,2.0,4.0,16.0,100]}
Gridsearch=GridSearchCV(estimator=Ridge(),param_grid=param_g,scoring="r2")
Gridsearch.fit(X,y)
Gridsearch.best_params_

The code below is the one generating the error:
ridge=Ridge(alpha=2)
cross_val_score=cross_val_score(ridge,X.values,y.values,scoring="r2", cv=kf,n_jobs=-1)

This is the error the code is generating:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 2
      1 ridge=Ridge(alpha=2)
----> 2 cross_val_score=cross_val_score(ridge,X.values,y.values,scoring="r2", cv=kf,n_jobs=-1)

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

I am not expecting any error. I use similar code in another project and it works smooth. I use cross_val_score to get better result.

Problem may be that you called variable cross_val_score just as function from sklearn. When you run the code multiple times, the variable cross_val_score from the previous run shadows the function, causing a TypeError because you are attempting to call a numpy.ndarray as if it were a function.

Please try to keep the example minimal, how is "Some parts of the code" related to the code that you think is generating the error?

When you first invoke cross_val_score, it refers to the imported function from scikit-learn. As you assign the result to a variable of the same name (cross_val_score), the scikit-learn function definition is overridden by the result of the function and cross_val_score become of type numpy.ndarray.
To resolve the error, you can name the result of calling the function cross_val_score differently:
cv_score = cross_val_score(ridge, X.values, y.values, scoring="r2", cv=kf, n_jobs=-1)


Np. Please accept the answer in this case.
